# Append multiple VNCoreMLModel ARKit and CoreML

Tags: swift, append, arkit, coreml

I'm a noob and I don't really know how can I happened multiple CoreML model to the VNCoreMLRequest. 
With the code below is just using one model but I want to append also another model (visionModel2 on the example below). Can anyone help me? Thank you!

```
private func performVisionRequest(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer){
    let visionModel = try! VNCoreMLModel(for: self.iFaceModel.model)
    let visionModel2 = try! VNCoreMLModel(for: self.ageModel.model)
    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: visionModel){ request, error in

        if error != nil {
            return
        }

        guard let observations = request.results else {
            return
        }

        let observation = observations.first as! VNClassificationObservation

        print("Name \(observation.identifier) and confidence is \(observation.confidence)")


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if observation.confidence.isLess(than: 0.04) { 
                self.displayPredictions(text: "Not recognized")
                print("Hidden")
            }else {
                self.displayPredictions(text: observation.identifier)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate an image using multiple ML models, you’ll need to perform multiple requests. For example:

```
let faceModelRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: visionModel)
let ageModelRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: visionModel2)

let handler = VNImageRequestHandler( /* my image and options */ )
handler.perform([faceModelRequest, ageModelRequest])

guard let faceResults = faceModelRequest.results as? [VNClassificationObservation],
    let ageResults = ageModelRequest.results as? [VNClassificationObservation]
else { /*handle errors from each request */ }
```

(Yes, you can run Vision requests without a completion handler and then collect the results from multiple requests. Might want to check [`prefersBackgroundProcessing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrequest/2875404-preferbackgroundprocessing) on the requests and dispatch everything to a background queue yourself, though.)

After that, you probably want to iterate the results from both requests together. Here’s a handy way you could do that with Swift standard library sequence functions, but it assumes that both models return information about the same faces in the same order:

```
for (faceObservation, ageObservation) in zip (faceResults, ageResults) {
    print(“face \(faceObservation.classification) confidence \(faceObservation.confidence)”)
    print(“age \(ageObservation.classification) confidence \(ageObservation.confidence)”)

    // whatever else you want to do with results...
}
```

<sup>Disclaimer: Code written in StackExchange iOS app, not tested. But it’s at least a sketch of what you’re probably looking for — tweak as needed.</sup>